# My first VB program, Error

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program for my brother, to show him what VB is. I had my friend help me here, but I now get an error when running on these lines.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Tick = 1000

    **Timer1.Start()**

End Sub
```

**the **'s arent there, I was trying to bold it.**

It returns me with this error:

`Error  1   'Public Event Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.    C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Form1.vb  10  9   WindowsApplication1`

Answer (score 3):

`Tick` is an `Event` of the timer. to set the interval use `Interval` property, or pass it to the constructor.

```
    timer = New Timer(3000) 
    timer.Enabled = True
```

Comment: Ahh thanks man, i was wondering if i needed to instanciate it like that.

Comment: no problem. Welcome to SO. if your satisfied with an answer don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: Just to clarify, if you added the timer to the form at design time, as you presumably did with the progressbar, then no, you don't instantiate it again in your code.